# Oracle Instant Client installed not in SSMS provider list WS2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, oracleclient

I simply would like to connect to an Oracle database from SQL Server.

- WS version: 2012
- SQL Server version: 2012 (v11.0.7507)

I'm having difficulties in properly installing the Oracle Instant Client 21.00.

It's showing in Drivers tab in ODBC Data Source 64-bit, as below:

[image: odbc data source drivers]

But is not showing under Providers in SSMS, as below:

[image: Providers in SSMS]

All documentation that I found mention the client showing up in Providers, I have done all sorts to make it so with no avail.

- Added relevant path to environment variables Path.
- Restarted server several times.
- Added Oracle db setting in `tnsnames.ora`
- Tried adding a System DSN data source (Now deleted)

Interestingly enough I have previously installed this in Win10 with no problems.

Comment: Is your SQL Server a 32bit or 64bit installation?

Comment: It's a 64-bit SQL Server

Comment: Side note, SQL Server 2012 ran *completely* out of support last year; you should really be looking at getting your upgrade plan finalised and implemented.

Comment: *"It's a 64-bit SQL Server "* And I *assume* that screenshot is taken on the SQL Server host, *not* your PC?

Comment: I'm using SSMS locally installed on the server, I'm not remotely checking from my computer.

Comment: I assume you've refreshed the Object Explorer after installing the driver? Also have you restarted the instance since it was installed (sometimes it needs one to pick it up in such menus, but it can still be referenced if you write the SQL to use said driver).

Comment: I have restarted the whole system and the sqlserver service a few times.

Comment: Linked servers use OLE DB providers rather than ODBC drivers. To use an ODBC driver via a linked server, you need to use the MSDASQL provider (Microsoft OLE DB provider for ODBC) and specify the Oracle ODBC driver in the connection string. That said, it would be better to use an Oracle OLE DB driver natively, such as the one included with [ODAC](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/odac-downloads.html). I don't believe Oracle Instant Client includes an OLE DB driver.